# How can I save user input from a Contact Form 7 into a Custom Table in my Wordpress database?

Tags: php, database, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a contact form called `Check In` that I want to store in the table `wpxo_checkin_forms`. The columns are: `userid`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `weight`, `checkindate`, `energylevel` (3 radio button options), `missmeal` (two radio button options), and `missworkout` (two radio button options).

I found this code here that I tried to modify and put in my child theme's function.php, but when I submit the form, it does not save in the `wpxo_checkin_forms` table.

What am I doing wrong here?

````
add_action( 'wpcf7_submit', 'SE_379325_forward_cf7', 10, 2 );
function SE_379325_forward_cf7( $form, $result ) {
    if ( ! class_exists( 'WPCF7_Submission' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    if ( 'mail_sent' === $result['status'] ) { // proceed only if email has been sent.
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
        save_posted_data( $posted_data, $form->id );
    }
}
// your insert function.
function save_posted_data( $posted_data, $form_id ) {
    if ( 1522 !== $form_id ) {
        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->insert(
            $wpdb->prefix . 'wpxo_checkin_forms',
            array(
                'userid' => $posted_data['userid'],
                'firstname' => $posted_data['first-name'],
                'lastname' => $posted_data['last-name'],
                'checkindate' => $posted_data['checkin-date'],
                'weight' => $posted_data['weight'],
                'energylevel' => $posted_data['energy-level'],
                'missmeal' => $posted_data['miss-meal'],
                'missworkout' => $posted_data['miss-workout']
            ),
            array( '%s' )
        );
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_submit', 'SE_379325_forward_cf7', 10, 2 );
function SE_379325_forward_cf7( $form, $result ) {
    if ( ! class_exists( 'WPCF7_Submission' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    if ( 'mail_sent' === $result['status'] ) { // proceed only if email has been sent.
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
        save_posted_data( $posted_data, $form->id );
    }
}
// your insert function.
function save_posted_data( $posted_data, $form_id ) {
    if ( 1522 !== $form_id ) {
        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->insert(
            $wpdb->prefix . 'checkin_forms',
            array(
                'userid' => $posted_data['userid'],
                'firstname' => $posted_data['first-name'],
                'lastname' => $posted_data['last-name'],
                'checkindate' => $posted_data['checkin-date'],
                'weight' => $posted_data['weight'],
                'energylevel' => $posted_data['energy-level'],
                'missmeal' => $posted_data['miss-meal'],
                'missworkout' => $posted_data['miss-workout']
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still not having success getting it to save :( I'm getting the e-mail notifications that the form has been submitted, but when I check the table, nothing has saved.

Are there any settings for the table or contact form I need to be weary of that could be causing the issue?

Comment: It worked for me. Is your table name 'wpxo_checkin_forms ' or does it have prefix at the front of wpxo_checkin_forms ?

Comment: Editing my comment. wpxo is the prefix, I believe. All other tables have that at the front.

Comment: I have edited my code now. This should work. I have tested it and it works on my end.

Comment: Thank you for your continued help. Unfortunately, it still did not work for me :(

I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong.

Comment: Are you testing this on live server or your local system. Do you get the email after form submission. You code inserts the data only after email sent so if the email is not sent the data does not get saved to database

Comment: I am testing on my local system. Could that be the issue? Yep, I do receive the e-mails.

Comment: I created a new contact form and test table and it's working... not entirely sure because I didn't do anything different, but maybe I'm just not realizing it.

My only issue is having the radio button option to save. I'm not sure what field type this would be.

Comment: What was the id of your form? Was it 1522? For radio button you need to select radio buttons on the form.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I have the radio buttons on the form, but I am not sure how to store the value the user selects into the database. It submits to the table as being blank but it records it correctly on the e-mail.

I tried text, varchar, boolean and haven't had any luck.